# Correctly bundling datatables.net.core nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatables, nuget-package, bundling-and-minification

How do I correctly bundle the nuget package [DataTables Core?](https://www.nuget.org/packages/datatables.net.core/) I have my BundleConfig.cs file setup as follows

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.ShippingMemo).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/App/Main.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.GiftCard).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/App/GiftCard.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryJS).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryUI).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryValidate).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.Modernizr).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.BoostrapJS).Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.DataTablesJS).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(Bundles.CSS).Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/fonts.css"
                  )
                  .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(Bundles.DataTablesStyle).Include(
            "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css"
        ));
    }
}

public static class Bundles
{
    public const string CSS = "~/Content/css";

    public const string DataTablesStyle = "~/Content/datatables";

    public const string DataTablesJS = "~/bundles/datatables";

    public const string BoostrapJS = "~/bundles/bootstrap";

    public const string JqueryJS = "~/bundles/jquery";

    public const string JqueryUI = "~/bundles/jqueryui";

    public const string JqueryValidate = "~/bundles/jqueryval";

    public const string Modernizr = "~/bundles/modernizr";

    public const string ShippingMemo = "~/bundles/App/Main";

    public const string GiftCard = "~/bundles/App/GiftCard";
}



}
```

And I am getting 404 errors on sort_asc.png and sort_both.png not being found, these files currently live in

```
\
\Content\images
```

Which is where the nuget package placed them after I installed it. I have tried using

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(Bundles.DataTablesStyle).Include(
            "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()
));
```

This does not seem to fix the problem at all, Server is always looking for the images at

```
{siteroot}/images/sort_asc.png
```

Comment: So, I've seen that there's a bunch of files in the DataTables NuGet package. How do I now what to exactly include in the bundle? There's even some images!

Comment: Okay, I found the answer to my own question. So, the examples are a good reference to what we should add to the bundles. In this example: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html we learn that for a BS5 implementation we must add: `jquery-3.5.1.js`, `jquery.dataTables.min.js`, `dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.css` and `dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css`, and the necessary class to the HTML table element `table table-striped`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package maintainer released an update and everything bundles correctly now as of version 1.10.15.1

My working BundleConfig.cs

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.ShippingMemo).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/App/Main.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.GiftCard).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/App/GiftCard.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryJS).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryUI).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.JqueryValidate).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.Modernizr).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.BoostrapJS).Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(Bundles.DataTablesJS).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(Bundles.CSS).Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/fonts.css"
                  )
                  .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(Bundles.DataTablesStyle).Include(
            "~/Content/Datatables/jquery.dataTables.css"));


        //bundles.UseCdn = true;
        //BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/azalea39",
        //"http://azalea.com/web-fonts/Code39Azalea.min.css"
        //).Include(
        // "~/Scripts/azalea39"));

    }
}

public static class Bundles
{
    public const string CSS = "~/Content/css";

    public const string DataTablesStyle = "~/Content/datatables/css";

    public const string DataTablesJS = "~/bundles/datatables";

    public const string BoostrapJS = "~/bundles/bootstrap";

    public const string JqueryJS = "~/bundles/jquery";

    public const string JqueryUI = "~/bundles/jqueryui";

    public const string JqueryValidate = "~/bundles/jqueryval";

    public const string Modernizr = "~/bundles/modernizr";

    public const string ShippingMemo = "~/bundles/App/Main";

    public const string GiftCard = "~/bundles/App/GiftCard";
}
```